# Perl CAM::PDF not accepting filename variable

Tags: perl, pdf

I have used the CAM::PDF module to read the text content from PDF file. In a directory I am having list of PDF files, so i have used the code like below to read the text content, which is not giving me the text in $text variable.

```
my $Filepath = "E:/test/";
opendir (DIR, $Filepath);
while (my $filename = readdir(DIR))
{
next if ($filename =~ m/^\./);
$filename = $Filepath.$filename;
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($filename);
my $text = $pdf->getPageText(1);
}
```

But if I pass the filename directly into the CAM::PDF, then it is working. Like below code

`my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new("E:/test/test.pdf");
print $pdf->numPages(), " pages\n\n";
my $text = $pdf->getPageText(1);`

But my requirement is toread the PDF files one by one from the directory. 
Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

If your loop is not working, then you should add debugging to see if you're actually iterating through the files.  One thing you are missing is error checking on your `opendir` call.

```
my $Filepath = "E:/test/";
opendir my $dh, $Filepath or die "Unable to opendir: $!";
while (my $filename = readdir($dh))
```

Assuming the call to `opendir` doesn't fail and return a helpful error message, then add a `print` statement to see what is being returned.

```
{
    next if $filename =~ /^\./; 
    print "$filename\n"; # Let's do some debugging.
```

If your manual call to `my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new("E:/test/test.pdf");` works, then the error should be in the above.

Comment: @Miller-Yes now I added the error checking part also, I can able to print the file path and file name. `$pdf->numPages()` is printing the page number as 1. But `$pdf->getPageText(1)` is not working.

Comment: What does _"`$pdf->getPageText(1)` is not working"_ mean?  Do you mean it's returning an empty string?  Is it throwing an error?  If it's the former, there might just not be any text content to return.  I'd try another access method like `$pdf->getPageDimensions(1)` and see if that returns data.  If so, I'd say that your code is likely working as intended.

Comment: @Miller-I tried the `$pdf->getPageDimensions(1)` and it returns the values as 0,0,612,792

Comment: In addition, instead of giving the file path directly like `$Filepath="E:/test/";`, i am getting the file path from another text file. Then the `$pdf->getPageText(1)` is returning empty string.

Comment: The fact that `getPageDimensions` returns data shows that things are working correctly.  if `getPageText` is returning an empty string, there simply may be no text to return.  Open the PDF manually and see what it contains on page 1.  Even if you're able to read text, that text might actually be an image, and therefore `CAM::PDF` isn't going to be able to help you "read" it in so simple a way.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but I had the same(ish) issue, and it was actually a bug. Look up "Bug #97560 for CAM-PDF: Fail with decoded paths".

In summary the bug says: "It looks like passing a decoded string to the CAM::PDF constructor, the module can't handle the stream, because the decoding is inherited into
the stream."

Looks like this doesn't happen to all versions of perl. In my case, it was happening with v5.16.3, but not v5.10.

So what I did was to manually encode the the filename before sending it to CAM::PDF->new, as shown below:

```
Encode::encode("utf8", $filename);
```

And that worked for me!